# login to ssh and check ssh login of another server python

Tags: python, ssh

## This code only logins to a server and checks the connection.

I need to login to a server, say (A) and check ssh login to server(B) and from (B) I need to check ssh for (C). Please help me to convert this code or a new one to do the above. TIA.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import subprocess
import sys

HOST="MYIP"
COMMAND="uname -a"

ssh = subprocess.Popen(["ssh", "%s" % HOST, COMMAND],
                       shell=False,
                       stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                       stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
result = ssh.stdout.readlines()
if result == []:
    error = ssh.stderr.readlines()
    print >>sys.stderr, "ERROR: %s" % error
else:
    print result
print ("PASS")
```

Comment: Why using Python?
Wouldn't it be simpler using BASH?

Comment: Maybe you are right. I need toe explore using bash. Python,because our framework is on python itself so.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is something like the paramiko module

```
import sys, paramiko

if len(sys.argv) < 5:
    print "args missing"
    sys.exit(1)

hostname = sys.argv[1]
password = sys.argv[2]
source = sys.argv[3]
dest = sys.argv[4]

username = "YOUR USER NAME"
port = "YOUR PORT"

try:
    t = paramiko.Transport((hostname, port))
    t.connect(username=username, password=password)
    sftp = paramiko.SFTPClient.from_transport(t)
    sftp.get(source, dest)

finally:
    t.close()
```

you can also pass cmd commands into it like

```
def sshCommand(host,port,user,pwd, commands):
sshClient = initSSHClient()
try:    
    sshClient.connect(host,port,user,pwd)
    for command in commands:
        print(command)
        stdin, stdout, stderr = sshClient.exec_command(command)
    print(stdout.read())
    return 1
except:
    print("No Connection on port",port)
    return 0
```

Where commands is a list of commands that should be executed (ls or chmod)

Comment: Hi, Thanks for swift response.. However does this Work for Multiple ssh hops(Server A-> B-> C)? Can you confirm what will source & Dest? do here?

Comment: If you add the script on server B or you have a shared code on a shared drive then you can do it by writing a function that accepts cmd arguments that can be passed to your Code. (This is only improvised but should work).

Answer (score 0):

I think that using Python for this specific task will not be the best.

Therefore I suggest you to use this simple bash script:

```
ssh -q user@server exit
result=$(echo $?)

if [ $result -eq 0 ]; then
    echo "ok"
else
    echo "ko"
fi
```

Save this script on Server A and then +x and run it:

```
ssh user@serverB ssh user@serverC exit
result=$(echo $?)

if [ $result -eq 0 ]; then
    echo "ok"
else
    echo "ko"
fi
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. The first script you mentioned works. But the second doesn't seem to work. Will this Work for Multiple ssh hops(Server A->Server B-> server C)?

Comment: Yes, I've just tested it.
The 1st bit connects from Server A to Server B and runs, as command, the ssh to Server C.
If all goes well you get "ok".
I will rewrite it for simplicity.

Comment: This takes into account that you have ssh keys working but I assume that is in place for security reasons

Comment: Thanks, I get it now. This should definitely work if I can call the 2nd script. Can you pls tell me how do I call the 2nd script? from server A? Another thing is that my ServerA might not be the same always. So everytime copying the 2nd script becomes manual right

Comment: I think that you can totally ignore the 1st script and just use the 2nd, if I've understood your request right.
If you think I didn't understand, what would your final requirement be?
It is easy to tweak the script to accept ServerB and ServerC as parameters too.

Comment: Please also remember to accept / upvote the answer if you find it useful

Comment: Hi Pitto, Below is the result I got when I used 2nd script alone.               root@IP password: 
Permission denied, please try again.
Permission denied, please try again.
Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password).
ko

Comment: My requirement exactly is that I have multiple server's for which i need to check SSh login. So SSH login should happen on hops. Ex:-I am running a script on Server(A). My script should check SSH to Server(B) and from Server(B) -> Server(C) and Server(C) -> Server(D) with results and should return the result to my script in Server(A)

Comment: Hi Pitto, Thanks again. All the above scripts provided by yourself &  Max Krappmann are of great help. Just looking for that script that matches my requirement exactly.

Comment: Hi there!
If you get a permission denied is because your ssh-keys were not set.